# Data Formatting and Fixing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, exploratory-data-analysis

I am trying to clean user reviews which they are crawled in the web. When I try to read on the pandas. There is no warning or error. Then print the lenght of the dataframe.

[image]

Then I would like to apply normalization step. But I am focusing on Turkish language,so I cannot use python library. I will use third party software.

For this purpose, I am trying to write reviews columns to text file. When I write to these data text file lenght of the sample is

[image]

and target size:

[image]

Basically I do this:

[image]

**Note**: As I mentioned these are the customer reviews, as we expected they are dirty and noisy. Some of the samples contains many enter characters such as approximately 56 of the sample contains "\n\n\n\n". I have tried solve this problem in python by cleaning data but every time I am losing sample. Also I tried to fix it on Excel, it did not work.

**Question**: Do you have any suggestion for fixing data?

Comment: There is *no* data here, what to fix? See [mcve], please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are producing two CSVs files from your `df` and then read them back as `reviews` and `targets`.

If you use `pd.read_csv` to read them back, [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has this argument `skip_blank_lines=True` by default which skips blank lines. If some rows of your original `df` contains only a number of '\n', then it will end up with an empty line in your new CSVs which will be skipped the next time they get read.

You can verify this by setting up two counter variables for the total number of empty lines and see if that matches with the 'loss'.

```
num_empty_review = 0
num_empty_target = 0

for ..., ... in df.iterrows():
    review = ...replace('\n', '')
    target = ...replace('\n', '')
    if review.replace(' ', '') == '':
        num_empty_review += 1
    if target.replace(' ', '') == '':
        num_empty_target += 1
    ...
    ...
print(num_empty_review, num_empty_target)
```

Lastly, next time, please paste your code here in text form like what I did in above :)